# What is it called when you can log into multiple workstations with one username and password

Tags: login, remote-login

At work with One username and password I can log into any computer with one username and password. - microsoft

A while back I was at a infoshop and they had 5 computers and 1 server. (Ubuntu or Linux mint)  I could log into any of the workstation computers with my username and password.  and my files where there on that computer

A while back in high school '98-00  there was a similar setup Log into any computer and you are in your environment - apple

What is that called?  and specifically what is that called in Ubuntu  I would like to have one environment with files and programs and log into it from my login screen

Comment: I would asssume you mean "multiseat" ? Easiest version: 2 or more  thin clients (=screen+keyboard+mouse but not an actual computer itself) connected to 1 server. Nowadays we use computers with their own OS and "shares" to connect to a server.

Comment: It's called network login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two separate issues:

On the login side those systems would have been setup to authenticate off a central server, you're probably looking for something like LDAP

On the common environment, if I understand you correctly you're looking for all your settings and files to be shared to whatever terminal you log in to? --Which again means your environment needs to be hosted on a central server and your home dir network mounted when you login.

Neither is too complex but requires the whole system be setup for such so depends on what your context is - either talk to your sys admin (who probably won't want to re architect everything) or if it's all under your control then it's definitely possible - have fun